# Some heroku commands couldn't find my application

Tags: ruby, macos, heroku, rubygems

I can find my apps in `heroku apps` command, and also do some command to read information from app like `heroku addons --app appname`.

But I couldn't find my apps in some command like `heroku addons:add addon_name`, `heroku pg:reset`.

**Work commands**

`heroku apps`:

```
=== My Apps
my_app_1
my_app_2
```

(Also I can see my apps in heroku web dashboard.)

`heroku addons --app my_app_1`(not in my_app_1 folder):

```
=== my_app_1 Configured Add-ons
shared-database:5mb
```

`heroku addons`(in my_app_1 folder):

```
=== my_app_1 Configured Add-ons
shared-database:5mb
```

**Doesn't work commands**

`heroku addons:add sendgrid`(in my_app_1 folder):

```
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app
```

`heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm my_app_1`(in my_app_1 folder):

```
Resetting SHARED_DATABASE (DATABASE_URL)... failed
 !    Resource not found
```

Here is my environment.

- Max OS X Lion (10.7.4)
- rvm 1.13.8 (stable)
- ruby 1.9.3p194
- heroku 2.26.5

Answer (score 1):

Adding the heroku's remote configuration to git did the trick for me. Validate if you have it configured with `git remote -v` on the terminal and you should get something like:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:your-app.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:your-app.git (push)
```

if you don't, add it with

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:your-app.git
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the latest version fo the Heroku gem (2.26.5) [is broken](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/351). A workaround is to downgrade to 2.26.3.

gem uninstall heroku -v 2.26.5
gem install heroku -v 2.26.3

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled version 2.26.5 and installed version 2.26.3. Now `heroku addons:add addon_name` works fine but `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` command still doesn't work. Is this command work on your environment?

Comment: 2.26.6 was just released so give it a spin.

Comment: Thanks. I installed ver 2.26.6 but `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` command still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a conflict between the Heroku gem, and the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/). I'm guessing you have installed the Heroku Toolbelt, but still have the Heroku gem in your gem file.

1. Remove the Heroku gem from your Gemfile and save.
2. Run the `bundle` command to update your Gemfile.lock
3. In Terminal, run `gem uninstall heroku` (NOTE: there may be multiple versions of the Heroku gem installed, and you'll need to uninstall all of them.)
4. In Terminal, run `heroku addons`
5. If you get `heroku: command not found` then you don't have the Heroku Toolbelt installed.
6. Install the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) and run the command again.

NOTE: If you're not in the app's directory, you'll need to add `--app myapp1` to the Heroku commands.

Hope this helps.